# Error occurs when I try to delete empty folder in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to delete an empty folder in Eclipse.

> An exception has been caught while processing the refactoring Delete. Reason: Problems encountered while deleting resources.

How can this be solved?

[image]

> I don't know reason but today when I try to delete this file. This
>   file has been deleted without problem. Thanks everybody for trying to
>   help.

Comment: Going to need some more details than that. Is it a read only file system? (Can you delete the file out side of Eclipse?) Probably a bug report would be more appropriate if this is a reproducible issue.

Comment: Open the details expander and look inside, maybe it is better open a bug on eclipse bugzilla rather then here on stackoverflow ...

Comment: ofcourse there is no problem in my os @awoodland

Comment: If you can't tell us how to reproduce the issue there's and no more details then there's no way for us to help you here. It sounds like a bug report is in order but they'll still want to know how to reproduce it.

Comment: Please attach a stack trace.  Go to Window -> Show view -> Error log.

Comment: I have solved problem thanks everybody for trying to help me

Comment: Generally, by doing a refresh on the folder you want to delete.  Closing Eclipse and opening it again does a refresh on all your projects.

Comment: I did refresh. But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how but today there is no same problem. I can delete files now.